# IE Conditionals suddenly stopped working after Windows XP Security update

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-7

Really bizarre stuff goin on here.  I installed some security updates for XP...then I fire up my text editor to do some coding, and realize that my IE conditionals don't work anymore.  Anyone have any suggestions for me?  I've Googled this til the cows come home.  I've tried uninstalling the updates, but Windoze keeps re-installing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a system restore....all is good for now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 'standalone' version of IE 6, 7 and/or 8 alongside the native version? The native installed version is the version that the conditional comments work with.

For instance, if you have IE 8 installed through software update, the standalone IE 7 and IE 6 will only execute anything within the IE 8 conditional comments.

Comment: This is not always the case. There are a few standalone IE installers that keep this functionality working properly in each version.